# Рабочий пример кода с onRestoreInstanceState

Tags: java, android

Напишите кому несложно какой-нибудь рабочий пример кода с сохранением состояния активити и восстановлением состояние при следующем её старте.

Никак не могу понять логики работы методов `onSaveInstanceState` и `onRestoreInstanceState` - метод `onSaveInstanceState` вроде отрабатывает а `Bundle` - нулевой.

Comment: Все есть в официальной документации, причем на русском даже: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html?hl=ru

Answer (score 6):

Метод `onSaveInstanceState(...)` вызывается между `onPause()` и `onStop()` и служит для сохранения данных (упаковки их в объект типа `Bundle`).

Метод `onRestoreInstanceState(...)` вызывается после `onStart()` и служит для восстановления данных (распаковки их из объекта типа `Bundle`). Данный метод вызывается только в том случае, если данные были сохранены (следовательно, проверка на `savedInstanceState != null` здесь не нужна).

Также, сохраненные данные можно восстановить в методе `onCreate(...)` (в большинстве кейсов их восстанавливают именно здесь).

Вот пример с восстановлением данных в `onCreate(...)`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String VALUE_KEY = "Value";
    private int mValue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mValue = savedInstanceState.getInt(VALUE_KEY);
        } else {
            mValue = 1;
        }

        Toast.makeText(this, "Value: " + mValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mValue = 2;
        outState.putInt(VALUE_KEY, mValue);
    }
}
```

При запуске приложения отобразится значение `1`, далее, например, если повернуть экран, то на экране появится значение `2`.

**Обратите внимание:** если Вы нажмете кнопку `Back`, а потом откроете приложение, то появится значение `1`, то есть сохранение значения не произойдет, так как нажатие на кнопку `Back` подразумевает под собой закрытие приложения (строго говоря, данные-таки сохранятся, но уже не восстановятся).

Нижеследующий пример демонстрирует восстановление данных с помощью метода `onRestoreInstanceState(...)`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String VALUE_KEY = "Value";
    private int mValue;

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        mValue = savedInstanceState.getInt(VALUE_KEY);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Value: " + mValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            mValue = 1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mValue = 2;
        outState.putInt(VALUE_KEY, mValue);
    }
}
```

При первом запуске `Toast` не отобразится, так как данные не сохранены и `onRestoreInstanceState(...)` не вызовется. Далее, при изменении жизненного цикла активити, будет вызываться `onRestoreInstanceState(...)` и отображаться `Toast` со значением `2`.

Comment: Спасибо за пример! У меня тоже все работало при повороте экрана - но как быть если состояние нужно сохранить при переходе от одной активити к другой (т.е. к примеру вы по кнопке переходим к другой активити а из неё так же по кнопке возвращаемся на данную) - у меня в этом случае сохранение не происходит