# Рабочий пример кода с onRestoreInstanceState Часть 2

Tags: java

Извиняюсь что наплодил похожих вопросов - просто не смог вставить код в прошлый вопрос:
[Рабочий пример кода с onRestoreInstanceState](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/660859/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%81-onrestoreinstancestate/660866#660866)

Подскажите почему onRestoreInstanceState не восстанавливает значение mValue при переходе с TwoActivity? Если делаю не так подскажите как это реализовать?(Сохранить состояния Активити и вернуть его при переходе на него с другой активити)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
private static final String VALUE_KEY = "Value";
private int mValue;
Button btn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mValue = savedInstanceState.getInt(VALUE_KEY);
    } else {
        mValue = 1;
    }

    Toast.makeText(this, "Value: " + mValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    View.OnClickListener Lisner = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,TwoActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
    btn.setOnClickListener(Lisner);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mValue = 2;
    outState.putInt(VALUE_KEY, mValue);
   }
  }

 public class TwoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btn2;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_two);
    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    View.OnClickListener Lisen = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(TwoActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
    btn2.setOnClickListener(Lisen);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых в `MainActivity` у Вас нет `onRestoreInstanceState`. Во-вторых в `TwoActivity` Вы открываете новый экземпляр `MainActivity`, а не возвращаетесь назад. Для возврата вызовите просто `finish()` в обработчике `onClick`.

Answer (score 0):

`onRestoreInstanceState()` не предназначен для этого. Он восстанавливает значения при вращении девайса или иных изменений конфигурации.